# Local copy of React prop is read-only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have two Components. The parent is passed an Object as a property, which it then copies into local data store. It has a function to update this local store, which gets passed down to a child. Here is my parent Component:

```
const Parent = ({stuff}) => {
  const store = {
    stuff: Object.assign({}, stuff);
  }

  const updateStuff = (thing, property) => store.stuff[thing].property = thing;

  return <Child stuff={stuff} updateStuff={updateStuff} />
}
```

The Child Component has a similar structure -- it makes a copy of `stuff`, and mutates its copy of `stuff` on an `<input>`'s `onChange`. It then passes its own updated copy of stuff to the `updateStuff` function it received, in order to mutate the Parent's copy of the prop. Here is the Child.

```
const Child = ({stuff, updateStuff}) => {
  const stuff = {
    thing1: Object.assign({}, stuff.thing1),
    thing2: Object.assign({}, stuff.thing2)
  }

  const setProp = event => {
    const update = event.target.value;

    stuff.thing1.prop = update;
    updateStuff(thing1, stuff.thing1.prop)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input id="thing1" onChange={setProp} />
      <input id="thing1" onChange={setProp} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Notice, I've used Object.assign to basically clone the `stuff` prop or its child properties, as the case necessitates. The reason for this: a React prop is read-only, and thus I need to create a clone to make changes on before passing it back to mutate the app's state (not shown here)/

Now, this works on the Child component -- `setProp` mutates the correct property of `stuff`, confirmed by logging to the console. However, when the method gets to `updateTeam`, I get an error message : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'side' of object '#<Object>'`

Yet, both Components use the same principle: I am not mutating the prop, but rather I am mutating a locally-stored clone of the prop. Why does this work for Child, but not for Parent?

Comment: This may be the result of Object.assign only doing a shallow copy. [Object.asssign reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone). Could you try deep cloning the objects anywhere you do Object.assign(). Something like`newStuff: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stuff))`. My thought is that the lower level parts of the object are not really a copy.

Comment: This actually solved the problem. If you format this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: So I guess the properties of `stuff` in my Parent component are actually references to properties of the actual `stuff` prop. Is that a correct analysis, @BrandonRoberts ?

Comment: Why, though, is this same thing not applying to my Child component?

Comment: If strict mode is enabled in App.js then may be instead of ```const``` use ```let```  i.e. ```const stuff = {
    thing1 ```  -> to ```let stuff = {
    thing1```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Object.assign only does a shallow copy of the prop [Object.assign Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone). In order to make a true deep copy of the prop (and get rid of the error) you can do a deep copy with `newStuff: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stuff))`. Glad this helped!

The real reason behind this is given in an example:

```
let original = {
    name: 'Test',
    nestedObj: {
        (...some properties)
    }
}
```

In the example above, the original object property 'name' is a new copy but the nested object is still a reference to the original. This way when you try and edit the part of the nested object it references the original and yells that it is immutable.

Comment: Many thanks... I still am unsure as to why this same thing didn't happen with Child -- considering that I am also mutating properties (of properties) of `thing`. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Here is a good answer to deep copy vs. shallow copy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy. This was really helpful to me when I ran across similar issues in react.

Comment: You sir are a high-quality user.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this question and decided it needs an updated answer. We can use `structuredClone(stuff)` instead of the older method of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stuff))`

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `const` to `let` for your local copies

Comment: Nope -- `const thing` only means that it's not a variable, and thus `thing` can't be reassigned -- so, if I say `const thing = { prop: 'value'}`, I can't re-assign `thing`, but I can change the value of `thing.prop`.

Comment: Are you assigning the property correctly? Should `store.stuff[thing].property` be something like `store.stuff[thing][property]`?

Comment: No. This is an issue specific to React.